# How to extract multiple email addresses in a Google doc?

Tags: google-sheets

This is the content of the cell and several like this. I need to extract only the email addresses.

[image: 1]

This is the function that I have so far:

`=arrayformula(regexextract(query(split( transpose(split(A1, ",")), ":" ),"select Col2 where Col1 contains 'email' ",0),"\w.+\w"))`

I have more than one cell with the info when I applied this function I am not able to drag down the function.

Comment: Welcome again to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried searching stack exchange for similar questions?

Comment: This is several days old. If you'd like additional input, A.) please respond to doubleunary below and B.) share a link to a copy of the spreadsheet *with realistic data already entered for a few rows in Col A*. I think I understand what you are trying to do, but it is not reasonable to expect the volunteers here to type out complex data into our own spreadsheets before even beginning to think through how to solve the issue. Help us to help you: share a link to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()`, `regexextract()` and `join()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  join( 
    ", ", 
    regexextract( 
      query( 
        split( transpose(split(A1, ",")), ":" ), 
        "select Col2 where Col1 contains 'email' ", 
        0 
      ), 
      "\w.+\w" 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: I used it but I can not drag it down- Hoy to change the formula so i CAN APPLIED TO ALL THE CELLS..

Comment: The above formula fills only one cell and can be dragged down.

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)